# I cannot find docker directory under /var/lib/

Tags: docker, macos

I have docker installed on Mac M1 and I want to access the -json.log file for a container. I found the location of the file using docker inspect but when I try to go to the location I get error saying docker directory does not exist.

I tried using screen command but it gave the same directory does not exist error.

Comment: Please click [edit] and include your [mcve]. Show how you started the container, how you found the log, how you tried to access it and what the error was.

Comment: Docker on MacOS runs in a hidden Linux VM, and you can't directly access the files like this.

Answer (score 1):

on MacOS use : ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/
or you can create shell script : screen   ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty

this article may be useful : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/where-are-docker-images-stored-docker-container-paths-explained/